# Fetch data from share for two sides

Tags: share, etl

there is a share with data on it for a ETL-process. Problem is, two sides need to fetch this data before the data can be deleted from share.

What is best practice to make sure both sides have fetched the data before moving data to trash?

Answer (score 0):

The data, when loaded, should be "registered". That is to say, a record should be written to a database to track that the file/data was loaded. Filename, row count, date found, date loaded, location on the share, a unique identifier for the data, etc.... all this should be tracked. If you are doing this and doing it at both locations where the data is to be loaded, then it is just a matter of having each destination for the data querying the other destination to see if the file has been loaded.

That or you can have a separate, 3rd process that is the "cleanup" process... deleted completed data/files. It would inspect the files located in the share and then inspect each destination to see if the file/data has been loaded. Once it has, this other/3rd process would handle the delete of the source data (or preferably the archive if not already archived earlier).